# decompile _underscore template

Tags: templates, backbone.js, underscore.js

i've got many "compiled" underscore template ( some months ago i save compiled templates to on file, and accidentally remove original templates folder... :( ) is it pissible to "decompile" this templates? one of example:

```
UV.templates["template-button-widget"] = function() {
        return $.trim(function(obj) {
            var __t, __p = "",
                __j = Array.prototype.join,
                print = function() {
                    __p += __j.call(arguments, "")
                };
            with(obj || {}) __p += '\n\n    <div class="button" data-id="' + (null == (__t = data._id) ? "" : _.escape(__t)) + '">\n\n        <div class="icon"></div>\n\n    </div>\n\n';
            return __p
        }.apply(this, arguments))
},
```

Comment: if you are using git - normally you can do revert to the commit where you deleted the folder.

Comment: don't use git for this project, but thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read over the [source](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-168) of `_.template`, you'll find it's simple enough that you could reverse it with a few hours of work. Make sure to find the code for your version of underscore (clearly yours isn't the most recent as there are changes), old docs can be found in the [changelog](http://underscorejs.org/#changelog).

Here's the code required to reverse your example template:

```js
var compiled = function() {
        return $.trim(function(obj) {
            var __t, __p = "",
                __j = Array.prototype.join,
                print = function() {
                    __p += __j.call(arguments, "")
                };
            with(obj || {}) __p += '\n\n    <div class="button" data-id="' + (null == (__t = data._id) ? "" : _.escape(__t)) + '">\n\n        <div class="icon"></div>\n\n    </div>\n\n';
            return __p
        }.apply(this, arguments))
};

var source = compiled.toString();

// Strip start/end code
source = source.substring(source.indexOf("with(obj || {}) __p += '\\n\\n") + 28);
source = source.substring(0, source.indexOf("\\n\\n';"));

// Reverse escape
source = source.replace(/' \+ \(null == \(__t = ([^)]+)\) \? "" : _.escape\(__t\)\) \+ '/g, "<%- $1 %>");

$('#result').text(source.replace(/\\n/g, "\n"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
<pre id="result"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually decompile it.. base on your code your template definition will be:

```
`<div class="button" data-id="<%= data._id %>'">
    <div class="icon"></div>
</div>`
```

It is easy but for complex template it will be harder.

Comment: thanks, but yeah, this is most simple template, i'm have more than 50 templates with "hard code"